# perl select specific column and store to different arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

there's a data :

```
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 101 family inet address 10.187.132.3/27 vrrp-group 1 virtual-address 10.187.132.1
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 102 family inet address 10.187.132.35/27 vrrp-group 2 virtual-address 10.187.132.33
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 103 family inet address 10.187.132.67/27 vrrp-group 3 virtual-address 10.187.132.65
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 104 family inet address 10.187.132.99/27 vrrp-group 4 virtual-address 10.187.132.97
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 105 family inet address 10.187.132.131/27 vrrp-group 5 virtual-address 10.187.132.129
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 106 family inet address 10.187.132.163/27 vrrp-group 6 virtual-address 10.187.132.161
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 107 family inet address 10.187.132.195/27 vrrp-group 7 virtual-address 10.187.132.193
set interfaces ge-1/0/2 unit 108 family inet address 10.187.132.227/27 vrrp-group 8 virtual-address 10.187.132.225
```

we need to extract some column and store it to a different variable. The data comes from after filtering a file, so it will be $_. Is there any method to store it to a different array?

```
$address[0] = "10.187.132.3/27"
$vrrp-group[0] = "1"
$virtual-address[0] = "10.187.132.1"

$address[1] = "10.187.132.35/27"
$vrrp-group[1] = "2"
$virtual-address[1] = "10.187.132.33"
```

I've tried using split but I don't know how to select spesific column on perl which is very easy done with awk (awk {'print $8'}).

```
@address = split(/\s+/, $_);
```

but it's failed.

Expected Result:

@address:

```
$VAR1  = '10.187.132.3/27'
$VAR2  = '10.187.132.35/27'
$VAR3  = '10.187.132.67/27'
$VAR4  = '10.187.132.99/27'
$VAR5  = '10.187.132.131/27'
$VAR6  = '10.187.132.163/27'
$VAR7  = '10.187.132.195/27'
$VAR8  = '10.187.132.227/27'
```

@vrrp-group:

```
$VAR1  = '1'
$VAR2  = '2'
$VAR3  = '3'
$VAR4  = '4'
$VAR5  = '5'
$VAR6  = '6'
$VAR7  = '7'
$VAR8  = '8'
```

@virtual-address:

```
$VAR1  = '10.187.132.1'
$VAR2  = '10.187.132.33'
$VAR3  = '10.187.132.65'
$VAR4  = '10.187.132.97'
$VAR5  = '10.187.132.129'
$VAR6  = '10.187.132.161'
$VAR7  = '10.187.132.193'
$VAR8  = '10.187.132.225'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-n` or `-p` with `-a` to simulate a similar [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) behaviour. [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) splits line with spaces and saves fields in the `@F` array, so you can select your desired positions:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -lane '
    push @array, {
        q|address| => $F[8], 
        q|vrrp-group| => $F[10], 
        q|virtual-address| => $F[12]
    }; 
    END { print Dumper \@array }
' infile
```

That yields:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'virtual-address' => '10.187.132.1',
            'address' => '10.187.132.3/27',
            'vrrp-group' => '1'
          },
          {
            'virtual-address' => '10.187.132.33',
            'address' => '10.187.132.35/27',
            'vrrp-group' => '2'
          },
          {
            'virtual-address' => '10.187.132.65',
            'address' => '10.187.132.67/27',
            'vrrp-group' => '3'
          },
          {
            'virtual-address' => '10.187.132.97',
            'address' => '10.187.132.99/27',
            'vrrp-group' => '4'
          },
          {
            'virtual-address' => '10.187.132.129',
            'address' => '10.187.132.131/27',
            'vrrp-group' => '5'
          },
          {
            'virtual-address' => '10.187.132.161',
            'address' => '10.187.132.163/27',
            'vrrp-group' => '6'
          },
          {
            'virtual-address' => '10.187.132.193',
            'address' => '10.187.132.195/27',
            'vrrp-group' => '7'
          },
          {
            'virtual-address' => '10.187.132.225',
            'address' => '10.187.132.227/27',
            'vrrp-group' => '8'
          }
        ];
```

---

**UPDATE**: The script equivalent to the previous one-liner (see *comments*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array;

while ( <> ) { 
    chomp;
    my @F = split;
    push @array, {
        q|address| => $F[8], 
        q|vrrp-group| => $F[10], 
        q|virtual-address| => $F[12]
    };  
}

print Dumper \@array;
```

Comment: how its implement inside the script?

Comment: @rabka: Which script? This is a one-liner. In the `END` section you have an array of hashes to do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: is it possible to insert it to a script? how we do that?

Comment: @rabka: I've added the script.